# Read YAML file in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, file-io, yaml

I am using OpenCV to save the `.yml`. Here is my code that I used

```
FileStorage fs;
fs.open("test", FileStorage::WRITE);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (block_hist_size * blocks_per_img.area()) ; i++ )
{
fs << "features" << dest_ptr[i];
}
fs.release();
```

Here is the output of the YAML file

```
%YAML:1.0
features: 1.5302167832851410e-01
features: 1.0552208870649338e-01
features: 1.6659785807132721e-01
features: 2.3539969325065613e-01
features: 2.0810306072235107e-01
features: 1.2627227604389191e-01
features: 8.0759152770042419e-02
features: 6.4930714666843414e-02
features: 6.1364557594060898e-02
features: 2.1614919602870941e-01
features: 1.4714729785919189e-01
features: 1.5476198494434357e-01
```

Can someone help me to read the yml file back to dest_ptr. I only need floating point values

Comment: i guess, above won't work. the FileStorage is basically a key-value store, your keys are not unique. what is dest_ptr ? can't you put it into a cv::Mat or such ? (easier to read back, too)

Comment: These are the HOG features for blocks only. With the below I am getting all zeros. I am trying to figure it out @berak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same key for multiple values. In your case you should store it as a vector of features. See code below

```
FileStorage fs, fs2;
fs.open("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "features" << "[";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    fs << 1.0 / (i + 1);
}
fs << "]";
fs.release();

fs2.open("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);
vector<float> a;
fs2["features"] >> a;
```

Comment: I am getting all zeroes @Tal Darom

Comment: ok, I missed the fact that you are using the same key for all features. updated my answer

Comment: yeah the same key feature is an erroneous condition. I am trying to solve that

Answer (score 1):

You must have misread the YAML specification, because what you produce with your code is not a YAML file.
In a YAML file mapping keys need to be unique as per the **Definition** for [generic mapping](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2802432) (and  you are using a generic mapping as you are not specifying a tag):

```
Definition:

    Represents an associative container, where each key is unique in the
    association and mapped to exactly one value. YAML places no restrictions on
    the type of keys; in particular, they are not restricted to being  scalars. 
    Example bindings to native types include Perl’s hash, Python’s dictionary,
    and Java’s Hashtable.
```

The **real** problem is that you try to make a simple YAML emitter doing string writes yourself. You should have created the data structure that you need in C++ and [emitted that](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToEmitYAML) structure, then the YAML would have been correct (assuming the emitter is not buggy).

Depending on what kind of file structure you choose you might have gotten:

```
%YAML:1.0
- features: 1.5302167832851410e-01
- features: 1.0552208870649338e-01
- features: 1.6659785807132721e-01
- features: 2.3539969325065613e-01
- features: 2.0810306072235107e-01
- features: 1.2627227604389191e-01
- features: 8.0759152770042419e-02
- features: 6.4930714666843414e-02
- features: 6.1364557594060898e-02
- features: 2.1614919602870941e-01
- features: 1.4714729785919189e-01
- features: 1.5476198494434357e-01
```

(a sequence of single key/value mappings) or:

```
%YAML:1.0
features: 
- 1.5302167832851410e-01
- 1.0552208870649338e-01
- 1.6659785807132721e-01
- 2.3539969325065613e-01
- 2.0810306072235107e-01
- 1.2627227604389191e-01
- 8.0759152770042419e-02
- 6.4930714666843414e-02
- 6.1364557594060898e-02
- 2.1614919602870941e-01
- 1.4714729785919189e-01
- 1.5476198494434357e-01
```

(a mapping of a single key to a single value that is a sequence)

As you experienced yourself it is non-trivial to create correct YAML for a data structure even simpler than this, using string writing. If you start with the appropriate data structure and emit that structure, you also know that you can use the same structure to read it back in.

---

<sub>In my experience the same holds true for generating XML/HTML/CSV/INI files, there having the correct data structure and using an emitter circumvents errors in the output format as well, compensating for any slightly higher complexity of the initial code.</sub>

Comment: Yeah I understand now. Thank you so much for the detail description.  Soon I tried to read the feature I got same key exception. @Anthon